# finding a float form a string without regex python

Tags: python, list, floating-point

I am trying to take an input from a "raw_input" function and make it into 3 floats and then sum them up.

```
user_input = "1.23+2.25+3.25"
```

is it possible to take the 3 numbers and add them to a list of floats that look like this or something similar?

```
float_lst = [1.23,2.25,3.25]
```

Comment: If you are 100% sure its always in that form, you can simply use `.split("+")` to get a list and then `map` to convert to floats.

Comment: Right. Is the only non-digit, non-dot character that can appear a `"+"`?

Comment: yes this is the only format it can show up as

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I only go by your requirement, not the list, you can eval. Trivial code example below

```
a = raw_input()
print eval(a)
```

Comment: Nice solution, but it is usually not a good idea to eval user input. If you don't "trust" the input you can use [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to safely evaluate input.

Comment: Thats true. Mea culpa.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

```
float_lst = [float(i) for i in user_input.split("+")]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the split function and then cast the elements to float.

```
user_input = "1.23+2.25+3.25"
lst = user_input.split("+")
lst = [float(i) for i in lst]
```

Now you have a list of float so you can do

```
result = sum(lst)
```

And you will have the result